# set an interval in a for loop to show up the results

Tags: javascript, events, output, intervals

hey guys I'm a noobie with javascript and I've been messing around with it and I was wondering if there is any chance of control the event that results in an output like for example a "for loop", here it's what i've got:

```
var stuff= ["cat","dog","parrot","wolf"];
var output = "";
for(var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++){
    output += stuff[i] + "</br>"; 
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
```

it will output inside my div 'result':

```
cat
dog
parrot
wolf
```

what I've been trying to do is to set intervals of 1 second between each output...so cat appear first then a second after dog and so on... is that possible? thanks in advance

Comment: setTimeout(continueExecution, 10000) //wait ten seconds before continuing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible, you use setTimeout( function_to_call, 1000 );

In your for loop you can use setTimeout at each iteration but the time is increasing as i is increasing in order to append the content to #result each second :

```js
 var stuff= ["cat","dog","parrot","wolf"];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
    {
        var func = function(index)
        {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += stuff[index] + "<br/>";
        }, 1000*index);
        }
        func(i);
    }
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

```
    var func = function(index)
    {
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML + stuff[index] + "<br/>";
    }, 1000*index);
    }
    func(i);
}
```

Comment: This will print `wolf` four times. You have to wrap the setTimeout function with a temporary scope to make this work...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible..

With `setInterval` (there is a 1 second delay at the beggining which can be fixed if needed)

```js
var stuff= ["cat","dog","parrot","wolf"];
var output = "";
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
     output += stuff[i] + "</br>";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
    i++;
    if (i==stuff.length){
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
},1000);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

---

**OR**

You can use the loop with `setTimeout` function.

```js
var stuff= ["cat","dog","parrot","wolf"];
var output = "";
for(var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){
            output += stuff[i] + "</br>"; 
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
        },1000*i);
    })(i);
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setInverval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval).

```js
var stuff = ["cat", "dog", "parrot", "wolf"],
  i = 0;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (i < stuff.length) {
    document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createTextNode(stuff[i]));
    document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    i++;
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutlely, there are a couple options depending on your needs:

For your example case the easiest way would be to use `window.setInterval`:

```js
var stuff= ["cat","dog","parrot","wolf"];
var interval=window.setInterval(reportContent,1000);

function reportContent(){
  output=stuff.shift();
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += output+'<br/>';
  if(stuff.length<1) window.clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

`window.setTimeout` will allow you to control each interval which is nice if you need granular control. If you need to pause for instance you can use `window.clearTimeout` by sending it the result of your `window.setTimeout` call. This can also allow you to enable that you never have 2 timeouts running at once.

```js
var stuff= ["cat","dog","parrot","wolf"];
var timeout=0;

function reportContent(){
  if(timeout>0) window.clearTimeout(timeout);
  output=stuff.shift();
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += output+'<br/>';
  if(stuff.length>0) timeout=window.setTimeout(reportContent,1000);
}
reportContent();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While javascript has no pause function per se, you can call a function after a given ammount of time. It's the set `setTimeout` function. You could do something like this:

```js
function printItemsToDiv(stuff, index)
{
  var output = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < stuff.length && i < index; i++){
    output += stuff[i] + "</br>"; 
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;

  if(index < stuff.length) {
    setTimeout(function() { printItemsToDiv(stuff, index + 1); }, 1000);
  }
}

var stuff = ["cat","dog","parrot","wolf"];
printItemsToDiv(stuff, 1);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```